# Re-registering a custom post type not working (not showing up)

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I registered a custom post type, but then I changed `register_post_type( 'studentenverenigingen', $args );` into `register_post_type( 'studentenverenigingen', $args );` . Now my client wants it back to the first one, so I changed it, but somehow it's not working now.

I don't see it in the admin bar and also the archive / url isn't visible either.

Who can tell me what is wrong with this:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Studentenverenigingen', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Studentenvereniging', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'VERENIGINGEN', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Studentenverenigingen', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Huidige Opleiding:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'Alle Studentenverenigingen', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Studentenvereniging toevoegen', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Studentenvereniging toevoegen', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Studentenvereniging aanpassen', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Studentenvereniging updaten', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'Bekijk Studentenvereniging', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'Studentenverenigingen bekijken', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Zoek een studentenvereniging', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Geen studentenvereniging gevonden', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Geen studentenvereniging gevonden in prullenbak', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
); $args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Studentenvereniging', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Studentenverenigingen informatie pagina', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 8,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'query_var'             => 'studentenverenigingen',
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'studentenverenigingen', $args );
```

Comment: Is this code inside a function?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you need. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so, check out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work. **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions) and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Comment: You may be running into a character limit. Try shortening the slug of your CPT (`studentenverenigingen`) and use `unregister_post_type('studentenverenigingen)` right before re-registering it.

Comment: Thank you WebElaine that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

function custom_post_type() {

custom postcode here

}

add Action hook at the end  of  functions

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );